# Does the UEFI variable namespace "{8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c}" have a standard name?

Tags: uefi

The UEFI standard defines various standard variables, for example `OsIndicationsSupported`, in the namespace identified by GUID `"{8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c}"`.

I need to declare that GUID as a constant in my code, and hence I need a name for it. I guess I could just make something up, but if there is a standard name for it, it would be better to use that. So does this namespace have a standard name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This GUID is officially called `EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE`. See [UEFI Spec Version 2.9
(March 2021), page 82 (page 157 of PDF)](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_9_2021_03_18.pdf):

```c
#define EFI_GLOBAL_VARIABLE \
{0x8BE4DF61,0x93CA,0x11d2,\
 {0xAA,0x0D,0x00,0xE0,0x98,0x03,0x2B,0x8C}}
```